# Locking in one thread, releasing in another

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a game server than can take requests from a user.  A user can request to place pieces.  The place method then spawns some async httpwebrequests (with timeouts) to find out if the placement was correct.  I want a lock that will be locked when the server receives the placement request, and will be unlocked by the web callback.  I would use a ReaderWriterLock, but that only works if I stay in the same thread, and the web request callbacks occur on different threads.  Is there another lock I should use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [a semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx). The locking thread acquires a permit. The async thread releases a permit. Semaphores are nifty because they aren't bound to individual threads.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx). Quote from the manual;

> The Semaphore class does not enforce thread identity on calls to WaitOne or Release.

In other words, you should not have a problem acquiring/releasing from two different threads.